# How to implement jQuery to specific class of class when when specific box is hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I want to implement jQuery to specific class of class when specific box is hovered?

I have a parent .Box div with .BoxHover div inside it.
I want to have 2 of this (i may need more in a page later) having the same class. (i don't want to use ID).
My target output is when I hover on .Box div 1, only the .BoxHover inside it will slide up.
My target output is when I hover on .Box div 2, only the .BoxHover inside it will slide up.

Currently, what happens is, all the .BoxHover divs appear when any .Box div is hovered.

My HTML:

```
<!--1st pic-->
<div class="Box">
    <div class="BoxPhoto">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/225x225/000000/ffffff&text=instagram_photo1" />
    </div>
    <div class="BoxHover">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/cccccc/000000&text=user_photo1" />
    </div>
</div>
<!--2nd pic-->
<div class="Box">
    <div class="BoxPhoto">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/225x225/ff0000/ffffff&text=instagram_photo2" />
    </div>
    <div class="BoxHover">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/cccccc/ff0000&text=user_photo2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.Box, .BoxHover {
    height:225px; 
    width: 225px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.BoxHover {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 20px auto -225px auto;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

My Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = 1;
    $(".Box").hover(function () {
        if (flag == 1) {
            $('.BoxHover').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            flag = 0;
        }
        else {
            $('.BoxHover').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -225, 'opacity': '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            flag = 1;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Bdw, I recently joined here, and not really into jQuery yet.  And it's my first time to ask question so please bear with me.  And I believe this question would be useful for others to answer. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dnxrywmb/1/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are targeting all `.BoxHover` elements in the `hover` handler instead of targeting only the `.BoxHover` element which is a descendant of the hovered `.Box`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Box").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.BoxHover').stop(true).animate({
            'margin-bottom': 0,
                'opacity': '1'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 300
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.BoxHover').stop(true).animate({
            'margin-bottom': -225,
                'opacity': '0'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 300
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dnxrywmb/)

Also use 2 different handlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of using the flag

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$('.Box').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.BoxHover').slideUp();
});
```

That's it.